# Which game controller is usable on Windows and Nintendo Switch without extra acessories?

Tags: gaming, linux, windows, video-game-console

I have a Nintendo switch to play Mario Kart, but I also use the controllers to play Dirt Rally on my laptop/desktop. Since my brother also plays Mario Kart, I want to have a second controller so he doesn't ask me for the controllers while I'm playing Dirt Rally. But since I want to also play on my Linux desktop, I don't want an extra pair of Joy-cons, because those are hard to pair with Linux. I also want an analog stick, so I can steer better in Dirt Rally. Analog triggers are nice, but not neccesary.

Update: I found that Steam remote play is also a thing, but thats also tricky to use because Steam crashes, so thats also not a good option.

Update: I removed Linux, because Steam and Wine bugged so hard I could not play Dirt Rally

Comment: I believe you aren't counting a Bluetooth adapter as an extra accessory? All of the Switch controllers are Bluetooth, so anything that works for both will always need Bluetooth on PC too. Pairing joy-cons is the same process as pairing any other Switch accessory over Bluetooth.

Comment: I do have a bluetooth dongle, so you don't have to count that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's an old question but I have found the Gulikit controller, it has magnetic sticks (no stick drift), has support for Switch (on Switch mode), Windows (on Xbox mode) and Linux (also Xbox mode although Switch mode is also supported on Linux). It also has analog sticks and triggers on both sides, Switch layout and a pretty long battery life. It can also be used wired in Switch mode and has turbo functionality